# Create Map<String,Char> with the first and the last character of a String

Tags: function, kotlin

I want to create output: First letter is K and n for second letter, but i dont know how to Map this code

```
fun main() {
    val text = "Kotlin".getFirstAndLast()

    val firstChar = text["first"]
    val lastChar = text["last"]

    // TODO 2
    println("First letter is $firstChar and $lastChar for second letter")

}

// TODO 1
fun String.getFirstAndLast(): Map<String, Char>{

    return mapOf()
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/map-operations.html ... find the first and last char from the given string and use put to add something to the map.

Comment: `mapOf("first" to first(), "last" to last())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [String](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/) is an implementation of [CharSequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char-sequence/) you can use [first](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/first.html) and [last](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/last.html) functions from it. And you just want single pair of first to last then you can use [Pair](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/) instead of Map (just a suggesstion).

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val (firstChar, lastChar) = "Kotlin".getFirstAndLast()

    println("First letter is $firstChar and $lastChar for last letter")
}

fun String.getFirstAndLast(): Pair<Char, Char> =
    first() to last()
```

**And if you really want to use the map here:**

```kotlin
fun main() {
   val text = "Kotlin".getFirstAndLast()

   val firstChar = text["first"]
   val lastChar = text["last"]

   println("First letter is $firstChar and $lastChar for last letter")
}

private fun String.getFirstAndLast(): Map<String, Char> =
   mapOf("first" to first(), "last" to last())
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `first()` and `last()` function from `CharSequence` interface and build the map using `mapOf`, then use getValue() on the map to get the corresponding values:

```kotlin
fun main() {
   val text = "Kotlin".getFirstAndLast()

   val firstChar = text.getValue(FIRST_ID)
   val lastChar = text.getValue(LAST_ID)

   // TODO 2
   println("First letter is $firstChar and $lastChar for second letter")
}

// TODO 1
private fun String.getFirstAndLast(): Map<String, Char> {
   val first = this.first()
   val last = this.last()
   return mapOf(FIRST_ID to first, LAST_ID to last)
}

// these are useful to avoid code replication
companion object{
   const val FIRST_ID = "first"
   const val LAST_ID = "last"
}
```